# Changing status bar style after viewDidLoad in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

So I know that in my ViewController.m I can override my

> -(UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle

method to change the return of the preferredStatusBarStyle.
But here's the thing: I have a property

> @property UIStatusBarStyle *customPreferredStatusBarStyle

and I'm changing the value of customPreferredStatusBarStyle in this bridge block:

```
[_bridge registerHandler:@"setStatusBarHandler_iOS" handler:^(id data, WVJBResponseCallback responseCallback) {
_customPreferredStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}]
```

which means if the website calls the bridge I'll change its value. But I found out that `**-(UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle`** method only gets called once when the ViewController is initiated.

Is there any way for me to change my status bar style after the the bridge gets called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call:

Obj-C

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Swift

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Comment: So by calling this method my `-(UIStatusBarStyle) preferredStatusBarStyle` will get called again?

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think you can call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` to trigger an update to status bar update.

Comment: Yes I've made it. Thanks!